# SuperSu not at all functional, can't uninstall

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

I installed SuperSU from Google Play, and then from a zip file using ClockWorkMod and now it crashes every time I go to log or settings. I tried factory reset, not quite sure how I thought it would help, and it's still broken. I'd like to uninstall it if possible. Fixes are also welcome, tough.

Edit: I'm using LG Nexus 5 with Android 5.1.1, Cyanogenmod 12.1 and ElementalX N5 2.11 kernel.

Comment: I think you should edit and clear the question, for example : download link or refrence for get the best result on reply.

Comment: Have you tried re-flashing your ROM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, I installed the newest version of CyanogenMod and fixed root.

Comment: Cyanogenmod 12.1 (mentioned in question) is already the newest version. Did you not mean newest *build*?

Comment: Yes! I am not too familiar with software terminology quite yet, but build is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

- First, you need to install the [SuperSu Zip](http://download.chainfire.eu/396/SuperSU/) file from recovery; then,
- Install the latest version of [SuperSu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) app from Play Store.

Also, based on my experiences on Cyanogenmod ROMs, **these ROMs are rooted before installing**. So, you don't need to install any `SuperSu` file from recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need SuperSu for Android 5.0x? See this video to learn how to enable root

[Enable Root Access in CyanogenMod 12](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pos3aBhzUnA)

The Root app tasks are now handled natively by the Privacy Guard in CyanogenMod 12+